# Debug webstorm with AngularJS and Browserify

Tags: angularjs, debugging, intellij-idea, gulp, webstorm

I'm building an `AngularJs` web application in WebStorm. I use `browserify` as a bundling package, and `gulp` as a task runner.

I tried setting breakpoint on the individual Javascript file in `Webstorm` and run Debug. But, I'm not unable to hit the breakpoint.

Also, I tried debug a `angularjs` application without `browserify` and `gulp`. I was able to debug in Webstorm.

Is it possible to run debug in a bundled javascript file? How would we make that work?

If not, what could be the reasons?

Comment: There's a known issue with debugging using browserify source maps. Please refer to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14454#comment=27-1016776 for some details on configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this problem. We will need to upgrade to Webstorm 10. Webstorm 9 doesn't support source map in debugging mode.